How to control echo of a spawned process in expect(1)?
How to properly set and get echo status of the terminal associated with a spawned process in expect(1)?
stty -echo executed immediately prior to spawn does not seem to affect the spawned terminal. While set stty_init -echo does, I found no equivalent for querying echo status.
The only hack I found to work on my machine was to use stty(1) as follows and then parse its output:
spawn sh -c "$main_command && stty -a"

However, I'm sceptical of robustness of that hack.
There's also tty_spawn_id, which I thought I could use as an argument to the stty expect command, but its contents make no sense to me: it's e.g. exp5 and not /dev/ttys5, which I would expect.

After spawn, the pty name is saved to $spawn_out(slave,name). You can then use stty(1):
$ expect -c 'spawn sleep 1; set pty $spawn_out(slave,name); puts $pty; puts [exec stty -a --file $pty]; expect eof'
spawn sleep 1
/dev/pts/10
speed 38400 baud; rows 57; columns 168; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff
-iuclc -ixany imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke -flusho -extproc


Thanks, that's useful. What happens if the spawned process exits before the expect script reads from $spawn_out(slave,name)?

Separately: in macOS, that construct uses a different term: replica. So the whole construct looks like this: $spawn_out(replica,name). Be aware of that when searching the man page.

"What happens if the spawned process exits before the expect script reads from $spawn_out(slave,name)?" -- PTYs are created in pairs. when the spawned process exits the Expect script is still opening the pty master so the pty slave is also alive so stty(1) can still get info from it. but i think the result is not reliable since the spawned process may have reset the pty before it exits.


the spawned process may have reset the pty before it exits
So it might be that && stty -a hack I described is more reliable than $spawn_out(slave,name), which I didn't know about. Thank you, @pynexj.


i'd not say cmd && stty -a is more reliable. for example, for vim && stty -a, stty cannot get the runtime tty info of vim.
